How to obtain class, coordinates and score after importing tflite model in android studio with kotlin
So i have trained a YOLOv8 object Detection model with 10 classes and 30 epochs and converted it into a tflite format with this code
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
model.export(format="tflite")

after importing this model in the android studio

File->New->Others->import tflite model

I received this code
val model = BestFloat32.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(image)
val output = outputs.outputAsCategoryList

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()

so how do i obtain my class scores and coordinate form it
model info image after importing
i have tried to print the

outputs by ==>outputs.outputAsTensorBuffer.toString() but it gave me a hexadecimal type value
outputs by ==> outputs.outputAsTensorBuffer.floatArray.toString() but it still gave me a mix of alphabets and number
outputs by ==> outputs.outputAsTensorBuffer.floatArray[i].toString() where if I keep i any value some floating points are generated

and when ever i print output = outputs.outputsAsCategoryList i receive an error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Label number 1 mismatch the shape on axis 1

how do i fix this ?
